# VenderID and ProductID

Tags: hid

In [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225201/how-to-use-a-dll-written-for-vb-net-in-c-sharp?newreg=c5c0605d36c647f08679768800b73685):

The follow Const is set as Integers.

```
Private Const VendorID As Integer = &H1234        'Replace with your device's
Private Const ProductID As Integer = &H1234      'product and vendor IDs
```

Some product and vendor IDs have characters in them. Is this code for specific devices?

Thanks

Ralph

Answer (score 0):

This is how you write hexadecimal values in VB.NET;
&H1234 is a hexadecimal value corresponding to 0x1234 in C#.

Comment: To enhance this answer, you can find a list of VIDs on [this list from usb.org](http://www.usb.org/developers/tools/comp_dump) (note that they are in decimal). PIDs will be assigned within a company and it's up to them to manage and track them.