# Can a VB.NET windows forms app reference and call a function in a C# DLL that references a C++ DLL?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, dll

Can a VB.NET 2017 Pro windows forms app project call a wrapper function in a C# DLL project that calls a function in a 3rd party x86 .NET Framework 3.5 DLL?

The VB.NET and C# wrapper DLL are mine.

Comment: Did you even try?

Comment: Many times, before wasting many hours of precious development time, I chose the wiser course of first asking Stackoverflow community regarding feasibility, only to learn there was indeed severe, showstopper reasons why NOT to attempt an idea.  Time is a limited resource -- unless you're in your 20's.   :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's possible. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8225255/2624611)

From [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhc3fa7f(v=vs.140).aspx) :

> Some CLS-compliant language compilers, such as the C# or Visual Basic compilers, enable you to specify that you intend your code to be CLS-compliant. These compilers can check for CLS compliance and let you know when your code uses functionality that is not supported by the CLS. The C# and Visual Basic compilers allow you to mark a program element as CLS-compliant, which will cause the compiler to generate a compile-time error if the code is not CLS-compliant.